# Text File Edit: Find unique multi line entry and edit

Tags: oracle, vbscript, tnsnames

I'm working with an Oracle TNSNAMES.ORA file which can and does get customized by end users as necessary. When global updates are required, these customization's make things complicated as overwriting globally isn't possible (I'd loose everybody's customization's). I've been successfully using a "Find & Replace" VBScript to edit this file and have had no issues. For instance, I've needed to change all instances of "(SID = CP03)" to "(SID = CP12)." The change I need to make now, however; is a bit more complicated.

I need to change the following multi-line entry from:

```
Server.world =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = server.company.com) (Port = 1521)))
                 (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = cp03))
  )
```

to:

```
Server.world =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = server.company.com) (Port = 1524)))
                 (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = cp12)
  )
```

I do not need to change every instance of Port 1521 to 1425 nor do I need to change every instance of SID CP03 to CP12. The Server.world entry is a unique variable but will be on a different line number for a lot of users. I tried using my 'Find & Replace' script but I cannot figure out how to 'find' a multi-line string. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

What would be the cleanest, most efficient way to do this via vbs? Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: I suspect your best bet would be to use a regular expression. Have you considered that?.

Comment: A regular string replacement should suffice here. Simply build the search and replacement strings by concatenation: `"something" & vbNewLine & "or other"`.

Comment: Why don't you use Oracle Directory Naming (using LDAP) for managing such requirement?